# gcloud problems with pip install

Tags: python, ubuntu, conda

I am running an ubuntu 14.04 instance on google's cloud compute engine. I have installed anaconda (python 3.5.0) and want to install additional packages via pip and also upgrade some manually.

```
pip install arch
```

I get the following error

`Command "/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-10ckqqqa/arch/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-tsgsc6n0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-10ckqqqa/arch/`

Other packages (`seaborn`, `pymysql`) were install without problems via pip. First I thought it is related to the `arch` package but I also noticed updating `pip install numpy --upgrade` raises an error as well, with the following error:

`Command "/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-5hogbswt/numpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-xrahrzqb-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-5hogbswt/numpy/`

The source of the problem is most likely not library dependent, what do I miss here to get the instance properly working ?

Comment: What is in `install-record.txt` files ?

Comment: I figured out the problem, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing `gcc` on my instance. Running `apt-get install gcc` as `sudo` solved the problem for me.